# Reduce not handling 0 == a properly

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

Consider

```
Reduce[a == 0 \[Implies] a == 0]
Reduce[a == 0 \[Implies] 0 == a]
Reduce[a == 0 ∧ b == 0 \[Implies] a == 0 ∧ b == 0]
Reduce[a == 0 ∧ b == 0 \[Implies] a == 0 ∧ 0 == b]
Reduce[a == 0 ∧ b == 0 \[Implies] 0 == a ∧ 0 == b]
```

The first four predictably produce `True`, but the last gives

> ```
> (b == 0 && a == 0) || a != 0 || b != 0
> ```

which is: a) incorrect, and b) why all of a sudden?

---

#### Edit

My questions remain. However, in the meantime I have been looking for workarounds. I started with looking for patterns like: `Equal[a_, (b_Symbol | b_Subscript)]`, with the intent to switch around `a` and `b`, then `ToRules[]`, etc.

However, I stumbled upon `LogicalExpand[]` which does the switcheroo by itself:

```
Reduce[a == 0 ∧ b == 0 \[Implies] LogicalExpand[0 == a ∧ 0 == b]]
```

producing the desired `True`.

Still waiting to hear your thoughts about the questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your last expression, you can use `Simplify[]`:

```
Reduce[a == 0 ∧ b == 0 \[Implies] 0 == a ∧ 0 == b] // Simplify
```

which returns `True` as expected. This kind of situation happens for algebraic expressions also. Sometimes you need `Expand[]`, `Factor[]`, or even `FullSimplify[]` to produce a `True` for an equation. There may be other ways, specific to logical expressions, such as `LogicalExpand[]` which do similar kinds of transformations.

The problem arises because Mathematica only uses a limited number of automatic simplifications. For example `(x + y) + (z - x) == y = z` returns `True` while `(x - y)(x + y) == x^2 - y^2` returns unchanged unless `Expand` or `Simplify` or `Factor` is applied before it also returns `True`.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. I still do not understand why it happened all of a sudden with the last form only. ATB, Aharon